# Guessing Efficiency

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two students A and B use two different mechanisms of guessing answers of $n$ multiple choice questions with 4 alternatives given.

> A randomly chooses the alternatives, while B  constantly chooses the same alternative (for example: he bubbles the option A for all n questions on the answer sheet) if the answers of the questions are distributed evenly...can one show the efficiency of mechanism using  probability ?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Certainly, B can get close to n/4 questions, correctly, but I have no idea how to calculate the efficiency of A's mechanism

Comment: We want to compare the expected number of correct answers for each.  B's expectation is ${n\over4}$ as you said.  To get A's expectation use linearity of expectation.

Comment: See, I don't know that concept(linearity of expectation). I am a highschool junior.

Comment: You probably know the concept, but not the name.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

We want to compare A's expectation (the average number of answers he will get correct) with A's expectation.  As you said, B's expectation is ${n\over 4}$ because it's simply the average number of questions with the constant answer he puts down.

For A's expectation, we use the fact that the expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations.  That is, the average number of questions that A gets right is the average number of times he gets question $1$ right, plus the average number of times he gets question $2$ right, plus ... .  Now he clearly gets each question right one-quarter of the time, so his expectation is also ${n\over4}$.

Comment: So can we say they have equal efficiency, I mean B is certain that he can get n/4 correctly, but A is not right ?

Comment: Well, it depends on what the question means when it says that "the questions are distributed evenly."  If it means there are an equal number of correct answers for every choice, then you are right, but note that A may also get more than $n/4$ correct.  I'd say the strategies are equally efficient, but A's is riskier.  On the other hand, if it means that each question is assigned one of the answers with a uniform probability of $1/4$, then there is no difference between the strategies.